# MongoDB sometimes stops

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java

I have a Linux Server (CentOS) with 32GB RAM.

I installed the MongoDB with a Java application. But sometimes, the MongoDB stops to work. So I need to restart it.

I already used the `ulimit` linux command to change te open files limit to `64000`, but the problem still happens.

I'd like to know if somebody have some experience with MongoDB and can give me some tip about this problem.

Comment: Could you post some lines from the log at the time of the crash?

Comment: At the log file, the last line says: "Too many connections: 4000". But I think that isn't the real reason. I don't have the full file here now, but tomorrow I will post the last lines.

Comment: Do you have an out of memory error in dmesg?

Comment: AleFranz, I will see about it...

Comment: Here is my dmesg, but I didn't see any error: http://pastebin.com/tkTqVAiR

Comment: At the job, a have the log file from last crash moment. Tomorrow I will post here

Comment: Add the logs to the question and the mongodb config

Comment: The mongodb file config has only this three lines: dbpath=/data/db | logpath=/opt/mongodb/log/mongo.log | auth=true

Comment: Maybe you can offer some piece of code in which you establish the connection - it should be located there. "too many connections" seems to be the reason for your issues...

Comment: But "too many connections" could really down the database? 
I think that the database only could't accept new connections...

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting "too many connections," it's quite possible you're opening too many `MongoClients`.  In general, you need only open the one client and its internal connection pool will manage everything for you.  This isn't always possible, though, so you'll want to make sure you properly manage the scope of each `MongoClient` and call `close()` on it when you're done.

Comment: any other reason from AWS t2.nano